# array difference and/or intersections in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to get the difference and intersection between arrays? (Possibly w/ dynamic arrays functionality)

I want {"a","b","c","d","e"}-{"a","b","c"} to return {"d","e"}

```
=FILTER({"a","b","c","d","e"},{"a","b","c","d","e"}<>{"a","b","c"})
```

didn’t work

P.S. For intersection, (which is the space sign in excel) it didn’t work either
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use ISERROR(MATCH()) inside the FILTER:

```
=FILTER({"a","b","c","d","e"},ISERROR(MATCH({"a","b","c","d","e"},{"a","b","c"},0)))
```

If the value is not found in the second array MATCH will return an ERROR.

[image]

Comment: wow, cool, thanks for the answer.. do you know how to do the intersection? NOT(ISERROR(MATCH won't work if I want the second array to be {"d","f"}

Comment: `=FILTER({"a","b","c","d","e"},ISNUMBER(MATCH({"a","b","c","d","e"},{"d","f"},0)))` will only return `"d"` as it is the only that both arrays have.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The `Scott Craner` answer works if the array constants (or ranges) are neatly in alphabetical order. But checking shows that if not, then the results aren't so clean.

My shot at it used `IFERROR()` instead of `ISERROR()` and seemed to work nicely. (`ISERROR()` works just as nicely without the `MATCH()` as it does with it. Except...) Then it occurred to me that the data might not be sorted and so, since both approaches depend upon position, that could lead to wrong results. For instance, switch the places of the "d" and "c" in the comparison left string. With `IFERROR()`, you get wrong results. With just `ISERROR()`, you get wrong results. Put `MATCH()` back in and you still get wrong results, though not in all cases.

I grant the data would likely be well-formed, like in the example, most likely. 90% of uses? 70%? 99%? Even if 100% for the poster, it might not be for someone else.

The following will work nicely even if the data is not well-formed for this purpose:

```
=FILTER(SORT({"a","b","c","d","e"},,,TRUE),IFERROR(SORT({"a","b","c","d","e"},,,TRUE)<>SORT({"a","b","c"},,,TRUE),TRUE))
```

The problem causing it all is that the comparisons are done positionally, 1st to 1st, 2nd to 2nd, and so on. Then `FILTER()` has a series of `TRUE/FALSE`'s matching its given range (or array constant's) positions. (That's why it has to be the five element array compared to the three element array, not the other way around. This way, there are five results to match the five elements being filtered, not just three results.)

So you have to be sure the items in the positions are apples to apples, not apples to oranges.

For a slightly more complicated situation, even that won't do it. Like `{"a","b","b","b","c"}` for the array constant, or range. That would take a more complicated formula and would depend a lot upon the given spreadsheet's actual data.